# Taylor expansion on Images which are warped

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm currently reading following paper: https://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/baker_simon_2001_2/baker_simon_2001_2.pdf

Here I struggle to follow the Taylor expansion from equation 2 to equation 3. I mean I know in general how Taylor expansion works, but in this case it is not clear to me.

Starting equation:

$$
\sum_{x} [ \mathit{I}(\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{p} + \Delta\mathbf{p})) - \mathit{T}(\mathbf{x})]^2 
$$

Taylor expansion

$$
\sum_{x} [ \mathit{I}(\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{p} )) + \nabla\mathit{I}\frac{\partial\mathbf{W}}{\partial\mathbf{p}}\Delta\mathbf{p} - \mathit{T}(\mathbf{x})]^2 
$$

Maybe somebody of you has more experience and can elaborate little more on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply the expansion twice. First for ${\bf W}$ up to first order in $\Delta {\bf p}$, we get

$$
{\bf W}({\bf x}; {\bf p} + \Delta {\bf p}) \approx {\bf W}({\bf x}; {\bf p}) + \frac{\partial {\bf W}}{\partial {\bf p}}\Delta {\bf p} \equiv {\bf W} + \Delta{\bf W}\tag{1} 
$$

Now for $I$ up to first order in $\Delta {\bf W}$,

$$
I({\bf W} + \Delta{\bf W}) \approx I({\bf W}) + \nabla I \Delta{\bf W} = I({\bf W}) + \nabla I \frac{\partial {\bf W}}{\partial {\bf p}}\Delta {\bf p} \tag{2}
$$

Putting everything together

$$
I({\bf W}({\bf x}; {\bf p} + \Delta {\bf p})) \approx I({\bf W}({\bf x}; {\bf p})) + \nabla I \frac{\partial {\bf W}}{\partial {\bf p}}\Delta {\bf p}
$$